# log4net c#, the installed program cannot write log to file

Tags: c#, logging, permissions, log4net

I can run program in VS2012 (Winform) in both release and debug mode.
It works  and writes log to file.

After I compiled to installable program with INNO Compiler. Then install complied program successful. The program works but no log file.

I change permission to full control and ownership. tried run as Administrator.

Still doesn't work. 
Thank you.

```
 <configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
```

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="C:\\printer\\log_"/> 

  <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date"/>
  <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd.\tx\t" />
  <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false"/>

  <lockingmodel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />

  <appendToFile value="true" />

  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />

  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<root>
  <priority value="ALL" />

  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</root>
<category name="DesktopLogger.Form1">
  <priority value="ALL" />
</category>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to (and have permission to) write to `C:\printer\log_`?

Comment: yes i still cannot solve

Comment: What happens if you change the output location to `value="${LOCALAPPDATA}\MyTest\debug.log"`?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is only guessing without access to your installer/machine. You can enable log4net logging to see what is going on:

```
<configuration>
...
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>

...

    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true">
            <listeners>
                <add 
                    name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                    initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

[Log4net FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html)